# Bounty button showing on answered questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

Why do I see the 'start a bounty' button on questions which have an accepted answer?

See the screenshot below from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/is-it-bad-practice-to-set-roots-shell-to-something-other-than-sh)

[image: bounty screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

Bounties are no longer tied to accepted answers. Just because the OP liked an answer and accepted it, doesn't mean that the answer is sufficient for you.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

You might still want an answer that goes into more detail or a cleaner way to solve the problem. So you still have the option to offer a bounty.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  However it begs the question, why don't I see the 'start a bounty' button on all answered questions?

Comment: @Griffo: You can't offer bounties on questions less than 2 days old.